# Splitting line from a file and storing as separate array values

Tags: java, arraylist, stringtokenizer

I have a requirement where in I need to read contents of a file, each line needs to be read into an array and split the line and store the values into separate variables for further processing.

**Sample data from the file**

```
175 31  4   877108051
62  827 2   879373421
138 100 5   879022956
252 9   5   891456797
59  421 5   888206015
```

**Expected output**

```
arr[1][1] = 175
arr[1][2] = 31
arr[1][3] = 2
arr[1][4] = 879373421

arr[2][1] = 62
arr[2][2] = 827
arr[2][3] = 4
arr[2][4] = 877108051

.
.
.
```

Im able to split properly using StringTokenizer but unable to access individual elements after tokens are formed. Tried with Array.split(), but its not splitting the values into separate array values. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

**My code**

```
static public void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File("small.txt");
    String[] lines = new String[100];
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
    int x = 0;
    String s;

    while((s = buffReader.readLine()) != null){
            lines[x] = s;

                // Using StringTokenizer
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(lines[x]);
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()){
            System.out.println("Next token:"+st.nextToken());
        }



        // Using Split() 
        String[] split1 = lines[x].split(" ");
        int size = split1.length;
        System.out.println("Split size:"+size);

        int i = 0;
        for (String value : split1) {

            System.out.println("Index:"+i+"  "+ value); i++;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the cause, but do not split by space. You may have tabs or LF characters, and/or leading and trailing spaces.

That is, do not use `lines[x].split(" ");`

split using regex.

```
lines[x].split("[\\s]+"); //one or more spaces.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify this code a lot.
Try something like this.

1) Read the file line by line, split lines as you go,
add values to some `ArrayList` containing `String[]`

2) Close your file

3) Turn the `ArrayList` into a `String[][]`

4) Print the result

Also, note that arrays in Java are indexed starting at 0 not at 1.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test021 {

    static public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File file = new File("small.txt");
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String s = null;

        ArrayList<String[]> lst = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        String[][] res = null;

        while((s = buffReader.readLine()) != null){
            String[] arr = s.split("[\\s]+");
            lst.add(arr);
        }

        buffReader.close();

        res = new String[lst.size()][lst.get(0).length];
        res = lst.toArray(res);

        System.out.println();

        // System.out.println(res);

        // String result = Arrays.deepToString(res);
        // System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println();

        for (int i=0; i<res.length; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<res[i].length; j++){
                System.out.println("res[" + (i+1) + "][" + (j+1) + "]=" + res[i][j]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
res[1][1]=175
res[1][2]=31
res[1][3]=4
res[1][4]=877108051
res[2][1]=62
res[2][2]=827
res[2][3]=2
res[2][4]=879373421
res[3][1]=138
res[3][2]=100
res[3][3]=5
res[3][4]=879022956
res[4][1]=252
res[4][2]=9
res[4][3]=5
res[4][4]=891456797
res[5][1]=59
res[5][2]=421
res[5][3]=5
res[5][4]=888206015
```

Comment: Final output of res array is again complete single line output, your code output ..                                        System.out.println(res[0][0]); => 175 31 4 877108051
System.out.println(res[1][0]); => 62 827 2 879373421
Whereas I want res[0][0] to be 175, res[0][1]=31 ...                         and res[1][0] = 62, res[1][1] = 827 etc... I want each value on the single line to be stored in separate array cell.

Comment: Each number is in separate "cell". I assumed you can at least print it as you want it. It's all in `res`, print `res` as you like.

Comment: Its still printing all values in single cell, output of your code is... res[1][1]=175 31 4 877108051
res[2][1]=62 827 2 879373421
res[3][1]=138 100 5 879022956
res[4][1]=252 9 5 891456797
res[5][1]=59 421 5 888206015                              
Problem got sorted once I changed lines[x].split(" ")  to lines[x].split("[\\s]+")

Comment: No, the output is not that. Answer updated. Check the things on your side.

Comment: This means your file did not contain just plain spaces but other separators (tabs for example). Good that it works now for you.

Comment: Yes 'small.txt' might be having other delimiters other than 'spaces', actual line splitting is happening only when I use split("[\\s]+"). Thanks for your help Peter. I request you to add regular expression based split() i.e [split("[\\s]+")] to your code, this will factor all kinds of separators and thus your code will work in all conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
     List<String> lines=new ArrayList<>();
```

Read file and add line to lines array

```
    File file = new File("data.txt");
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line = buffReader.readLine();
    while(line!=null){
       lines.add(line);
       line = buffReader.readLine();

    }
```

Convert lines array to string 2d array

```
   String string[][]=new String[lines.size()][0];
    for(int i=0;i<lines.size();i++){
        String s[]=lines.get(i).split(" ");
        string[i]=s;
   }
```

Comment: string[i][0] holds complete line.Output of "System.out.println("Index:" + i + "  " + string[i][0]);" for the first 3 rows is                                                         Index:0  175 31 4 877108051
Index:1  62 827 2 879373421
Index:2  138 100 5 879022956
Where as Im looking for string[0][0] to be 175, string[0][1]=31 ... and string[1][0] = 62, string[1][1] = 827 etc...